# Files not opening correctly with Notepad

Tags: notepad

Everything was fine yesterday. But today, when I open files with notepad, they open in a separate icon despite Notepad being pinned on the Taskbar. What's more is that hovering on the taskbar icon shows the name of another file and the icon is also not there. What could be the problem?

The most annoying, surprising, strange thing is that the text files themselves seem to be behaving like text editors.

[image]

Process Explorer:

[image]

It seems the correct file but there's no icon. I think it's corrupt. I ran `sfc /scannow` but that does *nothing*. It always says something like this:

> Found corrupt files
>   But can't repair.

Comment: You've probably installed another text editor which has become the default editor for `TXT` files. We'll need more details to effectively answer your question. A screenshot of this new icon that's supposedly not Notepad would be a start.

Comment: what is the new program name?

Comment: See the updated post please..

Comment: @FarhanAnam That could be a malware infection. Try running [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe) and press the **Find Window's Process** button (the one that looks like a reticle) and hover over the 'fake Notepad' window. After you do that, check to see which process is highlighted in Process Explorer. Double-click on the entry and click on the **Submit** button next to the VirusTotal box. Take a screenshot of that window and add it to your question. It should look [like this](http://imgur.com/weuAOXW).

Comment: @Vinayak Please wait a few mins. I'll do as you wish. I too think it's malware bcoz I am getting a **lot** of popup ads.

Comment: @Vinayak I have posted the screenshot. And forgot to do the Virus Total but it shows 0/54 now.

Comment: That's strange. Could you run `control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms` and check what program is associated with the `TXT` extension?

Comment: Ran MalwareBytes, 307 threats, *deleted all*, restarted. Still the same issue. And wait I'll run that.

Comment: Notepad @ `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe` is associated with `.txt`

Comment: If your system is badly infected, it might be hard to pin down the problem. Try running [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) and [Hitman Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro) in addition to doing a boot time scan of your hard drives with an antivirus with current virus definition updates.